# Instagram API access_token request and Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: javascript, ajax, instagram, access-token, same-origin-policy

## Context

I'm trying to get an **access token** from the Instagram API using their [server-side/explicit flow](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/).

When a user successfully authenticates and authorizes my application, Instagram redirects the user to my **redirect_uri** with a **code** parameter.
Once I've got this code, I'm trying to call the Instagram API in order to get the **access_token**.

## Problem

I successfully get this code but in order to make this exchange, I have to POST the code, along with some app identification parameters to their **access_token endpoint**:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token',
    // Disable credentials as they were enabled by default
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
    },
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {
        client_id: client_id,
        client_secret: client_secret,
        grant_type: 'authorization_code',
        redirect_uri: callback_http,
        code: token
    },
    }).always(function(res) {
    console.log('Res from Instagram API', res);
    });
```

The problem is that I get an **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** issue:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token.
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin '[here is my callback_http]' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I've tried using **dataType: 'jsonp'** as a parameter of the Ajax call without any success (401 code).

Any ideas? Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Comment: Server-side means that it must be accessed from your server :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use server side code for oauth when using serverside explicit flow, it is blocked by browser because of cross-origin request. if you want to use only javascript then use the client side implicit flow

Comment: Alright, I see.

By any chance, do you have any explanation why this exact same flow (a mix between server-side code thanks to NodeJS/Express routing and Javascript) is working for Dropbox but not for Instagram?

Comment: not sure may be their header has Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*. Also are you making the above instagram ajax call in node?, then it should work.

Comment: That'd be the best explanation. Actually no:
- Node matches the route after the Instagram redirect;
- then renders an HTML page where the above Ajax call is made.

I'm forced to do that as I want to POST the access_token to my API. Every call to my API must be signed (thanks to cookies), therefore made from the client-side.

Answer (score 0):

you can't unless its hosted in your domain or you own the url.

you can refer to this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy

if you are the owner of the server you can use htaccess to solve your problem. 
a question about how to solve that is in stackoverflow also..

Happy coding! :D

Answer (score 0):

**use window.location.href to avoid cors issues**

window.location.href = `https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?app_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&scope=${scope}&response_type=${responseType}`